# Uniquely identify Files and Directories on a Server for Comparison

Tags: php

What would be the best way to compare files and or directories. Lets say I want to store files on a sever or collective of servers like a cloud based system. My users are in collaboration with one another in many cases and some not. Either way I can have upwards of a hundred people or more with the same exact file. Only key difference is they likey renamed the file or whatever. But essentially same exact data all around. Now other thing is there is no specific file type. There's pdf, doc, docx, txt, videos, audio files, etc.. but the issue boils down to the same files over and over. What i want to do is cut it down. Remove the hundreds of dupes and with the help of a database store things like the file name the user provided so I can in turn store the single file left how and where I want while still providing the info they used essentially.

Now i know I can do something with md5 or sha1 or sha2 or something equivalent that will essentially give me a unique value I can use for such comparisons. But i am not exactly sure how or where to begin with that. Such as how with php can I get the sha or md5 of a file? When i look up stuff for those I get methods for strings but not files..

Overall I am here looking to bounce ideas around to figuring this out not so much as a direct means.. any help would be great.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$filePath = '/var/www/site/public/uploads/foo.txt'
$data = file_get_contents($filePath); 

$key = sha1($data);   //or     $key = sha1_file($filePath);
```

Save this $key in a column of table also mark that column as UNIQUE so no to same file can be stored by default.

Use sha1 instead of md5 since  many version control system like git use sha1 hash itself to identify uniqueness of file

Comment: +1: Only useful PHP code here… Ever tried to load a 1 GiB file into memory just to create a hash? PHP's memory limit bails out before... `sha1_file()` (or equivalent) to the rescue.

Comment: OR you could be masochist, and store `md5_file($file)` *and* `sha1_file($file)` in a database... just to be more safe :)

Comment: Not quite double: SHA1 = 160 bits, MD5 = 128 bits.  The solution to @Shi is to save the file in a temporary location and use an external program to do the hashing, for linux there's sha1sum.  Even better would be to store all files in a temporary location and use a daemon process to do the hashing and move the files / update the db.

Comment: @Zack Bloom PHP can do that directly, using md5_file() or sha1_file() or [hash_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php). Those functions work block-wise and don't load the full file in memory.

Answer (score 2):

When a file is uploaded:

- Compute the hash (SHA1, etc.)
- Rename the file to that hash and store it (unless a file with that hash already exists [you already have it])
- Store the hash in your database.

When a file is requested:

- Get the hash from your database
- Return the file based on the hash
- Use HTTP headers so the user's browser provides it to them with the filename they used

Comment: It is possible that two different files can have the same hash value. Hence item 2 could erase data.

Comment: The odds of that happening for a million files is 10^-37.  It's functionally impossible.

Answer (score 1):

To get the md5 hash of a file at `$path`...

```
$hash = md5(file_get_contents($path));
```

Hope this partially answers your question.

Comment: This is unlikely to work for larger file sizes.  Use `sha1_file()` instead ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php ).

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
md5(file_get_contents($filename));
```

To generate a hash for a file.

With that in mind, two entirely different files will produce the exact same md5 hash (Same problem with the other hashes, although you can have much less collisions by using a better hash method than md5). To compare two files you need to do it byte by byte, but you don't want to analyze every byte of every file on the hard disk to find a match.

What you need to do is store the hash for every file in your database in an a column, which should also be an index.

Then you can select all files with the same hash as the new file from your database.
That will give you a small list of files. Say you have 100,000 files on the disc. You might get a list of a few files that match the hash. Most of the time the lists will be short. Then you can loop through those files byte by byte to see if it's a match. Searching through a list of the ~10 files that have the same hash will save you from searching through all 100,000 files, but you still need to do the byte by byte comparison, because those 10 files could all be very different.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can accomplish such a system. But if I'd have to write one from scratch, this is most likely how I would do it :

1. have three database tables (in pseudocode) :

   ```
   table users {
      id integer         ## PK
      username string
      password string    ## sha1
      ...
   }

   table user_files {
      user_id integer    ## Composite INDEX
      file_id integer    ## 
      filename string
   }

   table files {
      id integer           ## PK
      uniq_id string       ## basically 'yyyMMddhhmmssRRRR' INDEX
      sha_hash string      ## sha1
      md5_hash string      ## md5
   }
   ```

   Where `files.sha_hash` is the result of computing the `sha1` of the file,  `files.md5_hash` is the result of computing the `md5` of the same file, as double security check, and `files.filename` the actual file name. On the server, the file would be stored and renamed to `files.uniq_id` to make sure there is no name collision, where the last `RRRR` chars represents a random string (cycle `RRRR` until `uniq_id` is unique in the database)

   **Note** : PHP provides [`sha1_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php) and [`md5_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php). Use these when computing files!
2. When a user stores a file, process the file (describe in step **1**) and save it appropriately. To avoid having too many files in the same folder on the server, you may decompose `files.uniq_id` and separate each files into `yyyy/MM` sub folders.

   Next, associate `user_files.file_id = files.id` and `user_files.user_id = users.id` and set `user_files.filename` to the uploaded file name (see next step).
3. If a user uploads another file, process the result as in **2**, but check whether the result match another `files.sha_hash`, `files.md5_hash`. At this point, if we have a match, it doesn't matter what name the file has, it's very likely the exact same file, so associate the found `user_files.file_id = files.id` and `user_files.user_id = users.id` and set `user_files.filename` to the uploaded file name.

   **Note** : this will cause to have `1` physical file and `2` virtual files on your server.
4. If a user rename a file without modifying it, simply rename `user_files.filename` matching the file he/she wants to rename.
5. If a user deletes a file, check how many `user_files.file_id` matches and only if `1` match is found, delete the physical file and the `files` entry. Otherwise, simply remove the `user_files` association.
6. If a user modifies the file with or without renaming it, perform a delete (step **5**) and another save (step **3**)

Answer (score -3):

1. Is it necessary? Hard disk is very cheap these days so who cares for the duplicates? I would imagine that are not that big?
2. MD5 et al. are not unique. Just a quick way of saying that two files are not the same. It is possible for two files to have the same MD5 value but contain different data.

Comment: 1. Why would you think they would be not that big?  Storing files by their hash is a very easy and effective way of eliminating duplicates and ensuring consistency (you can check the file's contents against it's hash).  2. Possible, but extremely unlikely.  They are cryptographic hash functions, no one has ever found a collision in SHA1.  Git, for example, stores all files based on their SHA1.

Comment: @Zack Bloom: I can easily proof there are collisions in SHA1: take any data size(n) that it bigger from SHA1 hash size(m) and take all combinations possible of that size and run SHA1 on them. you get 2^n hashes, but they only have m bits to be stored in. this is only possible when there is a duplicate.

Comment: I guess the op will write a cleanup script. So first, find *duplicate candidates* using a hash algorithm, then, if needed, do a byte-wise comparison to be sure.

Comment: He did mention that they are doc files etc. I would have thought that at most a file is going to be under 2GB, perhaps 4 at most. As to collisions - I agree that it may be unlikely but not impossible. For £60 you can buy a 2TB hard disk.

Comment: Shi - Seems a good solution - Just periodically have a 'spring clean' by comparing hash values of the files and those that are identical do a byte by byte check (only need to find the first byte that differs!). You can then dump one of the files and put a link in.

Comment: @Dani: Of course, but irrelevant practically.  SHA1 has 160 bits, assuming its optimal, the odds of any two files colliding is (NUM_FILES-1)/2^160 * NUM_FILES.  If he has a million files, the odds of a collision is on the order of 10^-37.  For comparison, that's roughly the odds of flipping heads on a coin 123 times in a row.  It is thousands of times more likely that he will have a fatal heart attack while writing the code than that he will have a collision.